# CH341DLL.DLL + I2C not works properly with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, dllimport, i2c

I write VB.NET class for implement CH341DLL.DLL functionality. The method *CH341StreamI2C()* is used for stream write and read into device. This way I've imported the method *CH341StreamI2C()* from DLL:

```
<DllImport("CH341DLL.DLL", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Shared Function CH341StreamI2C(ByVal iIndex As Integer, ByVal iWriteLength As Integer, ByRef iWriteBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal iReadLength As Integer, ByRef oReadBuffer As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

For check how this method works, I use I2C humidity and temperature sensor HTU21D. It's IIC address is 40h, and register where temperature is getting is E3h. So I invoke method *CH341StreamI2C()* like this:

```
Dim writeBuffer as Byte() = {&H40, &hE3} 'Address+Command
Dim s As String = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(writeBuffer)
Dim writeBufPtr As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(s) 'Get pointer for write buffer
Dim wLen As Integer = writeBuffer.Length
Dim readBufPtr As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero 'Init read pointer
Dim rLen as Integer = 3 'Sensor must return 3 bytes
Dim res As Boolean = CH341StreamI2C(0, wLen, writeBufPtr, rLen, readBufPtr)
```

I use logic analyzer to see what is on the SDA and SCL lines. And result is unpredictable. For example, if call previous code 4 times, that's the result:

[image: Lines SDA and SCL while CH341StreamI2C() calling]

It's seen, that physically CH341 device writes unpredictable values in the line. This is not DLL error, because other applications use this method and the result is correct. For note, other methods, e.g. *CH341ReadI2C()* and *CH341WriteI2C()*, that reads/writes only one byte per time, acts correct in my code.

What is the probably reason of the such behavior? May be, I've marshalled write buffer incorrect? How is the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the DLL's function declaration? I'm not so sure you should be converting it into a string.

Comment: Delete `ByRef` from the buffer arguments, they are passed ByVal.  Favor declaring them as Byte().

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](https://github.com/commandtab/ch341eeprom/blob/master/ch341docs/CH341DLL.H) is what you're using, the original declaration is:

```cpp
BOOL WINAPI CH341StreamI2C(ULONG iIndex, ULONG iWriteLength, PVOID iWriteBuffer, ULONG iReadLength, PVOID oReadBuffer);
```

Since the buffer parameters are `PVOID`s, you should be able to just marshal them directly to byte arrays:

```
<DllImport("CH341DLL.DLL", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Shared Function CH341StreamI2C(ByVal iIndex As Integer, ByVal iWriteLength As Integer, ByVal iWriteBuffer As Byte(), ByVal iReadLength As Integer, ByVal oReadBuffer As Byte()) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
```

Arrays are reference types (classes) which means you always refer to them via their memory pointer. Thus when you pass them to a function (P/Invoked or not) you're actually passing the array's *pointer*, rather than the array itself. This is really helpful when P/Invoking since it often lets you pass the arrays as-is.

Comment: @Aave : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!